# Android change device name

Tags: android, react-native

can i change bluetooth name or device name on android 10

like [this Button Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekaeb.jpg)  but from code

just for change bluetooth name
i try to use old way but not working here

```
BluetoothAdapter myBTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
myBTAdapter.setName("new_name");
```